# Telling my employer that I will get disappointed if I don't get a promotion

Tags: promotion

I work at a big company, in a field which is in a high demand nowadays. However, this is my 2nd year working at this company and this is my first job in this field.

Our company has a very structured way to doing promotions once every 2 years, and soon the promotion decisions will take place. Problem is that I am 2 months short from working 2 years a a company, so my manager told me that it's likely that I won't get a promotion, which means that I will stay in the same position for another year. However, I know that exceptions can be made.

I will of course try my best to show that I am a good candidate for a promotion and will do my preparation. However, would it be a good idea to somehow hint to my manager that if I don't get a promotion I would get really disappointed and demotivated (which would be 100% truth)? Keep in mind this manager it not the one who is making the final decision, but he would likely communicate that to those who make a decision.

I definitely don't want to sound like I am threatening anyone, but at the same time I feel like I will have more chances of getting a promotion if they think that I might leave if I don't get one (which is also true, I might consider leaving). Or do you think I might be perceived as not being a loyal and trusted employee by making these kind of statements?

Comment: @gnat, I am asking about specific case; question you linking to does not address my question at all.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I just asked him about that in an informal way because we get a long very well. He simply stated that based on his experience.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, no I just feel like it would be good to inform about my intentions/feelings.

Comment: "I feel I will be demotivated and leaving if I don't get promoted" *is* a threat, even if you don't exactly *want* to threat your company. "If I don't get what I want, I do something that is bad for you" remains a threat, independently of the question if it is actually true or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do not threaten your employer.**

It doesn't matter if you actually want to threaten your company or not. If your statement can be perceived as a threat - and "I will be demotivated and looking for a new job if I don't get a promotion" is a threat, even if you try to belittle it - things will not go down well with your management.

The question if you are eligible for a promotion after 22 instead of 24 months is irrelevant in this case. Even if you had been there for more than 24 months, there will be a chance that you don't get promoted for whatever reasons there may be.

See it from the viewpoint of your company: Every two years, they evaluate who will be promoted. Every two years, a bunch of people will **not** be promoted. Do you think that you are the first one to be demotivated if he doesn't get a promotion? If they really would be susceptible to the threat that if you don't get a promotion, you might leave, they soon will only promote those who threaten them (because others might use the same tactics, especially if it works). So they just can't make decisions based on threats, and they probably will ignore it. The only thing to expect is that your relationship with your manager and the company management will deteriorate, because they will see your behavior as illoyal. The more so, if you formally are not even eligible for a promotion.

You can speak with your manager and state that being there for 22 months instead of 24 months should not be the main reason for a promotion rejection, because evaluating the quality of the work should be possible after 22 months as well, and being rejected just because of two months seems an overly formal reason.

But do not put pressure on the outcome. If you are lucky, your manager will adopt the idea and be able to establish that you get evaluated like someone who is there for more than two years. But still then, evaluation might come out not in your favor. That should be accepted, and if you really feel disappointed afterwards, you can still start looking for a new job.

Comment: You're right, I did not look at it from this perspective. However, the fact of the matter is that I will actually lose motivation to do my job good, simple as that. If I know that in another full year I won't get promoted (and afterwards I will almost definitely will, unless I really screw up), why should I do my best for this company? I know for a fact, that if I would get promoted I would work harder and make them more money in the end. What I would like to do, is simply pass this idea to them.

Comment: @user1880405, if you like the company you should not just be thinking about this year and next, but of the future.  If you stop working hard just because you didn't get your promotion "on-time" you are short-changing yourself for future promotions.

Comment: @user1880405, the more interesting question is: Why shouldn't you do your best? I think you are fixated too much on the promotion system of your company. Do your best, "make them more money", and paths may open up that you do not even see now. Promotion may be a formalized process in your company, but I would bet that the really interesting and rewarding stuff is distributed informally (like everywhere else). Oh, and never, never pass the idea to them that you only work hard if it constantly goes up for you. If it really is that way, think abut a change to a company where "up or out" is lived.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you should be talking about hypothetical negative scenario and your hypothetical reaction to it. Instead you should just express how much you are looking forward to, how much you have worked hard for it and how motivated you will be with this promotion.  It would implicitly mean exactly same thing what you are trying to convey that you will be really disappointed. It will just keep the discussion very positive.

On a side note, since you mentioned it is a large company, be prepared for everything. Reasons for promoting or not promoting someone are not 100% transparent. Your personal feeling may not be even accounted for in these decisions.

Comment: Didn't even think about this! Indeed seems like a good idea to come from a more positive side of things.